# How to protect API Key in Flex/AIR from decompiling?

Tags: api, security, apache-flex, air, api-key

No obfuscation please and simpler the better.

Similar post is [Shared secret with API in an Ajax Adobe AIR app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294777/shared-secret-with-api-in-an-ajax-adobe-air-app) but I was not convinced that these protect from decompiling. If they do, please explain (For example, what's stopping someone from decompiling and using the URLLoader themselves).

Comment: It's the DRM problem: you need the key locally to do it's work, which means anyone with enough time and motivation can find it. At best, all you can do is obfuscate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the public key is in your code, there is nothing that can ever stop anyone from decompiling your app and getting the key.

Also - if the key is sent unencrypted from the AIR app to the server, it is a piece of cake monitoring the net traffic and retrieving the key from there. So even if you protect the key by storing it encrypted, you're pretty much screwed.

If you want to protect it, you have to send your calls through a proxy server that you control and keep the key there.

Comment: Your 3rd idea is good, I could see how that could work. Is there an easy way to do this? It seems like there should be someone providing a trusted key store for OAuth or something. This also seems like a pain too tho since my aim is for a desktop app.