# How secure is AIR's EncryptedLocalStore on the desktop?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, api, air

I'm working on a desktop application that uses API keys for Twitter but AFAIK, AIR applicatioons are easy to decompile. I want the processing of the API requests to be client-side, not server-sided. At most, I want to keep the dependency onto the server to as low as possible.

What I'm thinking is sending the API from the server to the AIR app on the first run. I've already seen [Shared secret with API in an Ajax Adobe AIR app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294777/) but my question is a bit different in that, I want to know how secure ELS is?

How does Adobe work it's way to storing stuff into the ELS? Does it go through multiple encryption sessions before finally getting stored somewhere on the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that an application on the user's desktop can read, can also be read by the user himself. They can get the key by using a proxy (like Charles) when you send it from or to the server; or they can read it with a debugger when AIR writes it to the ELS.

If I'm not mistaken, Twitter's API keys are public anyway (its only purpose is to track how you are using their API). Are you worried that a user might use your key for their own application? If they do that, all you have to do is get a new Twitter key.

Comment: The EncryptedLocalStore uses Adobe's key, not your key, to store information. You just tell it what to store and it encrypts it for you. Although an attacker may follow the program with a debugger, unless they know what key Air uses, (s)he will have a hard time discovering what your application has already stored in there.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning my mates app Charles FTW!

Comment: Thank you @Laurent, and yes I am worried that someone else might use my API key for their own. An example of how this could turn out bad would be if they used it for spam. The app's name could be in vain if that happens. Not that my application is already popular or would become popular, it's just that prevention is better than cure. As for getting a new Twitter key, how would I even know they are using my key in the first place?

Comment: @ShedoSurashu, not sure how it would work, but it just seems too easy to steal an API key and spam users with it, so I'd assume Twitter already has something to prevent it. I wrote several desktop clients on top of web APIs and the API key had to be public. You can always encrypt it, obfuscate the code and so on, but eventually if someone tries hard enough, they can get it. The only sure way is to do all the calls server-side.

Comment: Well actually, there's a public key and a private key. The public is the only one easily visible. Eh well, anyway, I guess I'll just have to store it in the EncryptedLocalStore.