# Use a python flickr lib to search images from tags - but without an api key

Tags: python, api, flickr

Does anyone know if something like this is possible? Do a quick search, using tags, for public flickr images, but without using an api ley, and retrieve images based on that search? (I already read [Why do I need a flickr API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86163/why-do-i-need-a-flickr-api-key), I want to know if there are libs that can do this search without it). Or maybe give a rss for a set, and have a list/dictflickr object of the images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, seduce a developer on the Flickr dev team and get them to open a back door for you. Or use your mad hax0r skills to do the same, sans seduction.

Seriously, though, Flickr says you need an API key to use their API. So you get an API key.

Or you could scrape the entire flickr site, building up your own metadata on the site. The compute and storage budget might be excessive.

Comment: Although this isn't exactly the answer I was looking for, I don't think it's really going to exist a lib that scraps a feed into Python objects or something like that, maybe because is too easy to get an API key (but you have to register as an application and have a flickr account). I was going to do a call 1 time a week in a simple script, so I thought the API key would be overkill.